# MySQL - query syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables.

```
news:
id
title

categories:    
id
name

newsEachCategories:
postId
categoryId
```

Table newsEachCategories holds the id of each post and the id of the category in which it has been posted.

So if post with id 13 has been posted in categories 6 and 7, there are two entries, one "postId 13 , categoryId 6", and one "postId 13 , categoryId 7".

So in order to find all posts that are in a category (say category with id of 5) I use:

```
SELECT news.title , news.editedTitle , news.id
FROM news JOIN newsEachCategories
ON news.id = newsEachCategories.postId
WHERE  newsEachCategories.categoryId = 5
```

How should I synxtax my query if I want to select posts that are both categories 5 and 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To return only results that exist in both categories, you may use a `COUNT()` aggregate and verify in your `HAVING` clause that 2 results are returned.

In this solution, I have joined against a subquery which returns the `COUNT()` per `postId`, and limits to those which are in both categories. That is joined back to the main table to get the remaining columns you wanted for that particular `news.id`.

```
SELECT 
  news.title,
  news.editedTitle,
  news.id
FROM
  news
  /* Join against subquery to count occurrences in newsEachCategories */
  JOIN (
    SELECT postId, COUNT(DISTINCT categoryId) AS postcount 
    FROM newsEachCategories 
    /* Limit to categories 5 & 6 */
    WHERE categoryId IN (5, 6)
    GROUP BY postId
    /* Ensures a result was returned for each category 5, 6 */
    HAVING postcount = 2
  ) postCounts ON news.id = postCounts.postId
```